# Expectation of the logit in logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic

When doing logistic regression with binary cross entropy (or equivalently cross entropy) loss, the model tries to approximate conditional probabilities as
$$
P(X\mid C) = \sigma(m(C)),
$$
where $X$ is an event, $C$ is some condition, $m$ is our (in case of logistic regression linear) model, and $\sigma(y) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-y}}$.

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_functions_for_classification#Logistic_loss), we know that the loss is minimized by setting
$$
m(C) = logit(P(X\mid C))
$$
where
$$
logit(y) = \log\frac{y}{1-y}.
$$

My first question is the following, do we know the expectation of the model? Is it equal to the expectation of the logit? Or, formally,
$$
E(m(C)) \stackrel{?}{=} E(logit(P(X\mid C))
$$

Second, if it is equal, can we somehow express this as a function of $I_X$, the indicator function of X, in the form
$$
E(f(I_X)\mid C) = E(m(C)),
$$
where we are looking for some $f$?

Edit: In hindsight this question was not just unclear, but incorrect in its formulas, sorry. What I actually meant to ask is if it's true that the output of the model (the logits) approximate the conditional expectation of something. Such as
$$
E(m(C)) \stackrel{?}{=} E(logit(P(X\mid C))\mid C)
$$